# how to generate unique title like wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, stub

hye im maya,
i need to generate unique title like wordpress.
if title **hello-world** is exist,the next title will be **hello-world-2**

thanks

Comment: This seems pretty simple, what language are you looking for?

All you have to do is check if the name exists on your database, if it does check if there is a number at the end, if it is add one to the number and make that your title, else add "- 2" to the title.

Comment: Pfft, why use titles that make sense? Just add the time of day and use a perfect digest function that doesn't have collisions and use that. :-P

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the server to see if that title already exists
2. If it does, append a `-2` and go to step 1. If you have already appended a `-2` and the title already exists, replace it with a `-3`, and so on.
3. If it doesn't, insert the file.

Example for step 1:

MySQL:

```
SELECT `title` FROM `table` WHERE `title` = '{$title}';
```

File (PHP):

```
$exists = file_exists("path/to/file");
```

Example for Step 2:

```
$iteration = 2;
while($exists){ 

      $newname = $file . '-' . $iteration;
      $iteration++;
      // Check to see if the file exists here

}
else{
    // Add the file here
}
```